# manipulação de palavras com Allegro

Tags: c, allegro

Olá,
Estou com dúvida sobre a manipulação de strings com allegro, assim como usar "fgets" ou "scanf" em C para receber uma palavra do teclado quero saber como faz isso com allegro.

Comment: Bem vinda ao **StackOverflow** Kamila, para fica mais fácil em ajuda-la, é recomendado que coloque junto da sua duvida a parte do código que está tendo o problema, assim fica mais fácil de fazer a depuração. Você pode clicar em **[Editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/204440/edit)** para fazer as auterações na sua pergunta.

Comment: A qual versão de Allegro você se refere?

Comment: Versão 4.4.2 usando o CodeBlocks como editor

Comment: Nesse caso, não sei ajudar. Acho que a comunidade do SO em Português não tem muito conhecimento de Allegro. Sugiro que você pergunte isso na comunidade em inglês, ou que faça essa pergunta em algum fórum oficial de Allegro. O principal site que me vem em mente é o https://www.allegro.cc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá pra ler letra por letra, eu ainda tenho uma função que utilizava para ler o nome do jogador, essa função ficava em um loop em conjunto com o textout, que desenhava o nome do jogador a medida que o mesmo digitava:

```
 char nome[200];

//FUNÇÃO PARA INSERIR NOMES
void LE_TECLADO()
{
    readkey();
    if(key[KEY_A])
    {
        strcat(nome,"A");
    }
    if(key[KEY_B])
    {
        strcat(nome,"B");
    }
    if(key[KEY_C])
    {
        strcat(nome,"C");
    }
    if(key[KEY_D])
    {
        strcat(nome,"D");
    }
    if(key[KEY_E])
    {
        strcat(nome,"E");
    }
    if(key[KEY_F])
    {
        strcat(nome,"F");
    }
    if(key[KEY_G])
    {
        strcat(nome,"G");
    }
    if(key[KEY_H])
    {
        strcat(nome,"H");
    }
    if(key[KEY_I])
    {
        strcat(nome,"I");
    }
    if(key[KEY_J])
    {
        strcat(nome,"J");
    }
    if(key[KEY_K])
    {
        strcat(nome,"K");
    }
    if(key[KEY_L])
    {
        strcat(nome,"L");
    }
    if(key[KEY_M])
    {
        strcat(nome,"M");
    }
    if(key[KEY_N])
    {
        strcat(nome,"N");
    }
    if(key[KEY_O])
    {
        strcat(nome,"O");
    }
    if(key[KEY_P])
    {
        strcat(nome,"P");
    }
    if(key[KEY_Q])
    {
        strcat(nome,"Q");
    }
    if(key[KEY_R])
    {
        strcat(nome,"R");
    }
    if(key[KEY_S])
    {
        strcat(nome,"S");
    }
    if(key[KEY_T])
    {
        strcat(nome,"T");
    }
    if(key[KEY_U])
    {
        strcat(nome,"U");
    }
    if(key[KEY_V])
    {
        strcat(nome,"V");
    }
    if(key[KEY_X])
    {
        strcat(nome,"X");
    }
    if(key[KEY_Z])
    {
        strcat(nome,"Z");
    }
    if(key[KEY_SPACE])
    {
        strcat(nome," ");
    }
    if(key[KEY_0_PAD])
    {
        strcat(nome,"0");
    }
    if(key[KEY_1_PAD])
    {
        strcat(nome,"1");
    }
    if(key[KEY_2_PAD])
    {
        strcat(nome,"2");
    }
    if(key[KEY_3_PAD])
    {
        strcat(nome,"3");
    }
    if(key[KEY_4_PAD])
    {
        strcat(nome,"4");
    }
    if(key[KEY_5_PAD])
    {
        strcat(nome,"5");
    }
    if(key[KEY_6_PAD])
    {
        strcat(nome,"6");
    }
    if(key[KEY_7_PAD])
    {
        strcat(nome,"7");
    }
    if(key[KEY_8_PAD])
    {
        strcat(nome,"8");
    }
    if(key[KEY_9_PAD])
    {
        strcat(nome,"9");
    }
    if(key[KEY_0])
    {
        strcat(nome,"0");
    }
    if(key[KEY_1])
    {
        strcat(nome,"1");
    }
    if(key[KEY_2])
    {
        strcat(nome,"2");
    }
    if(key[KEY_3])
    {
        strcat(nome,"3");
    }
    if(key[KEY_4])
    {
        strcat(nome,"4");
    }
    if(key[KEY_5])
    {
        strcat(nome,"5");
    }
    if(key[KEY_6])
    {
        strcat(nome,"6");
    }
    if(key[KEY_7])
    {
        strcat(nome,"7");
    }
    if(key[KEY_8])
    {
        strcat(nome,"8");
    }
    if(key[KEY_9])
    {
        strcat(nome,"9");
    }
}
```